# How to scrape music streaming header for infos

Tags: web-scraping

[image]I have a very long list of radio streaming links in an excel file, most of the streaming links when i inspect them through network developer tool of google chrome i see they have a header which contains some infos of the name of the radio and the type of music it streams..

I want to know if there is anyway to automatically scrape these infos, (Name, music type) please.

here is an example:
http://centova2.whsh4u.com:9007/stream?hash=1463479281647.mp3

infos:

icy-genre:Histoire - Culture - Musique

icy-name:Aquitaine Radio Diffusion

Comment: why do you want to scrap them? what will you do after that? what about simply ignore them and handle those you know are useful. to confront your question, you will need a full list of them. from https://cast.readme.io/v1.0/docs/icy , it seems ok to remove all start with `icy-`.

Comment: I have almost like 1300 radio link in an excel file as the example above, I want to organize them based on the channel name and genre, right now i only have the links, So I need the names and the genres, I can't do that manually it's extremely time consuming and boring. I can't scrap the icy because they don't exist in html, they exist as a header of the audio being streamed.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what tool you would like to use. In Python to get request headers you would do:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.google.co.uk")
print(r.headers)
```

Output:

```
{'Expires': '-1', 'P3P': 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Set-Cookie': '1P_JAR=2018-01-12-10; expires=Sun, 11-Feb-2018 10:54:36 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.uk, NID=121=U2phVKlO3UmL_jlK02Qj6J5K_uo6SLe1-hSWZsIA0fjlB82hEDT7D_69JYk9NRnCTFfhpviKsB-wRgoQKEDHsq6q7Cf8IWynKWHopoYHPWa8IPNhBD9r5dLsweNm52jS; expires=Sat, 14-Jul-2018 10:54:36 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.uk; HttpOnly', 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Alt-Svc': 'hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Server': 'gws', 'Date': 'Fri, 12 Jan 2018 10:54:36 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'}
```

I imagie your data would be there.

Comment: hello, thank you very much, that was a very good answer, a very close one to what i want, but sadly it didn't work.

here is what i got as a respone:

{'Server': 'squid/3.5.12', 'Mime-Version': '1.0', 'Date': 'Sat, 13 Jan 2018 01:25:22 GMT', 'Content-Type':
 'text/html;charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '810', 'X-Squid-Error': 'ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0', 'X-Cache': 'M
ISS from giles-liveproxy1', 'X-Cache-Lookup': 'NONE from giles-liveproxy1:3128', 'Via': '1.1 giles-livepro
xy1 (squid/3.5.12)', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

Comment: I updated my question with a picture of how the header look like, I am willing to use any tool even if i have to learn it from scratch..thanks